# How to use a different private port to a public port?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, port-forwarding, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is port forwarding and what is it used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for)

HI,
I would like to serve a webpage using port 80 publically but privately on my LAN it's available on port 90, now is it possible to handle this ?
Currently my page is only available if the user specifies the port 90 after the IP address?
I have a net gear router and can't seem to find anywhere to speificy a different private port.

Comment: If your router firmware does not support using different internal and external ports, you can always see if DDWRT is compatible with your router, it will do what you need.

Comment: Btw, all very well closing this topic as a duplicate but where is the original question, no clear sign posting to that on here as far as I can see.

Comment: @Rubans The question(s) a question is deemed to be a duplicate of are listed at the to. In this case pointing to [What is port forwarding and what is it used for?](http://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for).

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, but, not a lot of home routers support it.

When setting up a new firewall rule, some give the option of external IP and internal IP.

I do not think that Netgear support this feature... Sorry!

Comment: I believe you are correct, seems only available in certain routers

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to redirect the external port 80 to the internal port 90.

As you didn't specify your model, you can look at [portforward.com](http://portforward.com/) how it works for your router.

If yours isn't listed, it might not support the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Some NAT Routers can do it. Otherwise,

You need port translation software I don't know which.. this may do it

Softperfect Bandwidth Manager
it's mentioned here
http://markus.revti.com/2009/01/squid-transparent-proxy-server-on-windows-server-2003/
and downloadable here
http://www.softperfect.com/products/bandwidth/

if you figure out how to use it, then you can post a better answer than mine! maybe there's other software too, that looks like a 30 day trial.