# Bridge mode on router secure?

Tags: home-networking

Let's discuss in general, so there is typical home wlan router brand [something]. Administration is done via web browser. While on bridge mode it's not possible to access admin page unless setting some computer's IP to `192.168.1.x`. Is this safe concerning attacks from WAN port? Does one still have to care to have as hard password as possible (not default one) since remote/WAN access should not be possible at all?

(Another mode is usually "router" on these devices and there one can configure is admin access possible also from WAN or only local. On that mode better to select local..)

Comment: Per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq), please don't sign your posts. Your user card (a way of identifying you) is added to each of your posts in the bottom-right corner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly secure from the WAN side, because the router performs NAT and therefore must have an explicit port-forward rule in order for WAN users to get to the device (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for) for details on port forwarding). This is, however, insecure from inside your own network, so you should be careful to encrypt your network.

The upside is that the risk from exploit here is fairly low: since they must already have your network key (either by cracking or pwning the router), about the most they can do from the administration panel of the bridge is stop it from working properly. There is, I suppose, the possibility of installing some sort of malware, but I don't think this has been seen before in the real world.

Comment: Thank you also, sorry about not being specific enough, I'm just using box with wires so wireless features aren't that vital in my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it is a wired bridge mode and not AP then wired bridge. If that is the case, they'll have to bust through your router first. No doubt about that.

Comment: Yes, wired is the key here and protection against WAN access.. So according your answer I'm fine, thank you very much for conforming my thoughts!