# How to make any IP accessible outside the network

Tags: windows, firewall, ip, wamp

Is it possible to make my internal IP accessible outside the network? Something like `192.168.x.xxx`.

If I try my external IP, I get redirected to the website of the company. I'm on Windows and I'm using WampServer. I already disabled my firewall and selected 'put online' from WampServer.

Comment: Depends on *which service* exactly you want to make available. A web server only?

Comment: What is the model of your router or firewall? And what are you trying to make go through the firewall? We are not talking about your software firewall, local to your PC. If you post that, I can probably give you detailed instructions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set your firewall/router to use Network Address Translation (NAT) to [redirect the port](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for) you are trying to access on the outside/external IP, and redirect it to the internal IP at 192.168.x.x.

Comment: I probably wouldn't have any luck with that since I don't have the privilege to modify things on the router. But thanks for giving me the idea.