# How to make an FTP server on a Windows XP machine

Tags: windows-xp, ftp

How can I set up an FTP server on my Windows XP Machine?

(I have a static IP address)

Answer (score 2):

When you say "static IP" does this mean static in relation to your network (LAN) or the internet?

You'll need to install something like [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) server and open port 21 in your firewall. If you want to access it from the internet you'll need to ["port forward"](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for) your router to handle all port 21/FTP traffic through to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct if you only want to forward "command" requests. However, if you also wish to deal with "data" then you will need to open up port 20/tcp as well. This will allow you to transfer files. Both of these ports can also be configured to something else within [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) server but these are the defaults. Also port 21 needs to be TCP as well.