# Getting ip error error in html validation

Tags: web-development, validation

I installed firefox web developer tools when i try to validate page then i got an error. the screen shot of error below

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is port forwarding and what is it used for?](http://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: @Nifle how is this a duplicate?

Comment: @KronoS - It's been a while. But I suspect my reasoning was that the linked question explains the basics about localhost, routers and how to access local pages from the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RFC 3330](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330.txt) explains you why:

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host
>      loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an
>      address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host.
>      This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback,
>      but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network
>      anywhere [RFC1700, page 5].

The important part here is `loop back inside the host` which basically means that you are visiting the site on your own computer, hence it is `not public`. What you do when doing the validation is sending your `localhost` IP to them and they can't really resolve that as it's local to you. Hence, if you want to validate it with the click of a button you would have to host your site first...