# accessing fz ftp server whitin a network externally

Tags: ftp

as the topic goes, i have a filezilla FTP server  up and running. I have tested internally and it works well.

However, how do i set it to allow people to access the ftp server remotely via internet?

Comment: You need to forward the port you are using (probably 21) from your external IP on your router's WAN to the internal IP of the machine with your FTP server. This is done inside your router. There are numerous questions about that process on superuser.

Comment: i have a router and the router goes to the Fortinet Gateway and finally to the server.. do i need to configure for both ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for

Comment: @Melvin that would entirely depend on the configuration of the router and the fortigate firewall.  Please [edit] and add information about how the fortinet and router connect - IP addressing and routing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your router is set to forward your desired port (external) to the internal port your FTP server is running on. 
(For instance you may want to open port 21 for most FTP connections)

If you have a static IP address you may simply give that external IP address to anyone who wants to connect.

If you have a dynamic IP you may want to look into something like http://DynDNS.org.