# Connecting to FTP server that's behind a NAT

Tags: ftp, port-forwarding, nat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is port forwarding and what is it used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for)

So I want to allow my machine behind NAT to be accessible via FTP. However, as it is behind NAT, it is not possible to connect to its FTP service from outside.

Does port forwarding in the NAT router (or gateway) allow access?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, portforwarding should work, provided your router firewall is FTP aware, as there is a second connection established on a random port with ftp, which needs to be opened and forwarded automatically by the router.

A better approach would be to use a protocol that does not require this, and has the benefit of being more secure:  SFTP/SCP.  This does file transfers over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In your router you need to forward a port on your external IP to the internal IP of your FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The router that is performing NAT operations should port forward it your server. then it should work.