# How to connect to my lan from the outside (e.g. internet)

Tags: router, ip, lan, remote

I want that my router will see me as an inside the LAN host when I access him from an outside IP that is not in the LAN so I can access my printer and storage device that are connected to him. I can access his settings but not the storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up port forwarding so your router knows what you are trying to get to. i.e access your router WAN address with a specific port and it will translate that to an address inside your LAN. This way you can map a drive to your storage device and connect to your printer over TCP/IP.

Giving the model of the router will allow more detailed versions of this answer.

ALso I would recommend you look at this answer on SU: [What is port forwarding and what is it used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: VPN is probably the cleaner solution.