# Connect a PC in a LAN with shared Internet connection through a router

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote

I have a LAN in my office with shared Internet connection through a router.
I want to access a PC with remote desktop with only one public IP.
I know the computer's public IP and LAN IP which I want to connect.

How can I connect to this computer in my home?

Comment: Unless you have access to the router and can configure port forwarding, this is not possible.

Comment: i configured port.

Comment: You configured what port?  That makes no sense.  As I said before, you need to be able to manage the router, and set up [port forwarding](http://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for) so that requests to the `publicIP:somePort` are forwarded to `lanIP:3389`.

Comment: I configured 3389 port.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will get what you want much easier by using an assisted remote desktop application.

There are several: [GoToMyPc](https://www.gotomypc.com/members/), [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure *Port forwarding* and dig deep into the concept of `Tunneling` and `Reverse ssh` to get it work. Additionally you also need access of your LAN router to configure port forwarding. Bcz what undergoes is when you access internet through a PC which is configured with a Private IP (local LAN IP), it uses tunneling concept to get access to the internet through one common Public IP, but to get access from internet to your PC you need to establish *Reverse tunneling*, which in turn, uses *Port Forwarding* feature.

An easy way could be (only if VPN connection is available), if you have access to your office intranet in which the PC you want is present, so you can logon to the VPN network and access the PC.