# port forwarding issue with ZTE router

Tags: router, port-forwarding

Background at [android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49533/closed-ports-wifi-problem)

I have a ZTE ZXDSL 531B router in my home. I would like to open ports 5228-5230.

I don't see any `port forwarding` options in the router admin page. How can I instruct these ports to be open for forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like](http://www.pcwintech.com/port-forwarding-zte-zxdsl-531b-zte-firmware) your router decided to put the port forwarding options under an option named "Virtual Server."

Comment: I tried to follow the guide you mentioned (its little different than mine, could be firmware mismatch ) but its too much for a noob like me.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for