# Is there any way to serve http from behind a typical home NAT/router (from inside a LAN)

Tags: http, ipv6, p2p

I seem to remember reading that something in IPv6 could help with this. I thought I would ask here to see if per-to-peer http could be a possibility these days. I am familiar with hole-punching, but I gather that this is a UDP thing, not TCP.

Comment: You might want to check out this question: http://superuser.com/q/284051/820

Comment: Oh yes, I know about port forwarding; I was hoping that there might be some new ipv6 way to avoid it for serving http. This is what I am asking really.

Comment: If you're behind a NAT router than you need port forwarding.  The only difference IPv6 really offers is more addresses so that each device behind the NAT router can have its own publicly routed address instead of sharing the public address held by the NAT router, and in that situation you would remove the router and just have your devices directly on the internet.

Comment: @heavyd No, you wouldn't remove the router, it would still be there. It just wouldn't be doing NAT anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can serve HTTP from LAN behind router via IPv6, without doing port forwarding on the router. Usually you'll do that by installing IPv6 tunnel like [he.net](https://tunnelbroker.net/) or [SixXS](http://www.sixxs.net/) one.

Note, however, that you'll have to run your web server on IPv6, and only IPv6-enabled web clients will be able to connect to it. That is protocol limitation, IPv4 devices cannot talk to IPv6 devices, and vice versa.

Comment: Thankyou, you've really pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!