# Raspberry PI Server

Tags: raspberry-pi, modem, router

I'm working with a 3d printer. The printer is connected to a Raspberry PI B+. I've installed Repetier Server on it. The problem is that I can't access to the server outside my LAN network (if I use it's local IP, I don't have any trouble). I have a modem connected to a Tplink wired router (the router has the ports open). The raspberry is connected to this router. I tried to change this router for a switcher, but I have the same results. What can I do?

Comment: This sounds like a networking problem, better suited to, maybe, Superuser.se.

Comment: You need to configure your NAT (router) to pass the ports used by our RP to it's IP. But I don't think this belongs to this Q&A.

Comment: Here are the quick steps.  If you need more detail, ask at Superuser :)  1. Assign the RPi a fixed IP address.  You can do this either at the RPi (preferred) or by forcing your router to always assign the same address to the RPi.  2. Configure your router for "port forwarding". Any incoming ports required by Repetier should be forwarded to the RPi's fixed IP address.

Comment: Thaks for your answer. I forced the router to assign a fixed IP to my RP but didn't work

Comment: From outside of your network you'll need to access the RPi using your _router's_ public IP address.  You can find this address by typing "what is my IP" into google.

Comment: Ah, it looks like we've been migrated :)  [Here's](http://superuser.com/a/284073/314417) a related answer regarding port forwarding.

Comment: Unless “Repetier Server” has built-in access control, **you do not want to expose it to the Internet**.

Answer (score 0):

Like @gbulmer says it's a network issue, you can find the instructions on how to set up here https://www.repetier-server.com/manuals/0.50/index.html under  "Access the Server from Everywhere.

Basically you have to open port 2000 and redirect it to the IP of your raspberryPI.