# Making client/server with python that works outside my network

Tags: networking, router, python

I was trying to achieve simple client/server with python, 
there are a lot of tutorials samples and examples on how to achieve this in a scripting level.

My question is how should I approach this task in more theoretically Networking level:

Steps so far:

1. Setup Machine Client that will be host. windows 10, IP Behind router - 10.0.0.32 - for example.
2. Setup Machine Server that will be virtual-box-ubuntu. - IP Behind router 10.0.0.5 for example.
3. Found my Public IP -> via ipinfo io website.
4. Tried to connect my linux machine with PUTTY under public IP and got "error connecting due to software".

What should I consider and do to make them work due to the result they both share the same public IP?

Should I make some router changes?  if yes how ?

Should I contact my ISP and ask them for something ?

Will love your thoughts and ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to forward a port to access your machines through your router. **BUT BE CAREFUL** doing this. If you are opening your machines to the internet by forwarding ports, especially for SSH, you are opening yourself up to people getting access to your systems.

For your set-up, you would need to forward 2 ports, one for each machine. This would take a port from your router, and forward it to the port for ssh on each machine (usually 22 is the default).

Here are a couple of links for some more information:

[Purpose of port forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/1097744/purpose-of-port-forwarding)
https://portforward.com/

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why I need to make two forwards ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I thought you wanted access to both computers. The forward is needed so your router knows that any incoming connections from port XXX need to be sent to port YYY on your machine. What is likely happening at the moment is you are trying to connect via ssh to your local ip, which ends up trying to ssh into your router. This is then being blocked and you are seeing that error message