# Reaching a device in my LAN from the Internet

Tags: networking, remote-access

I have an embedded device that I can program via Ethernet IP when it's connected on the same router with the PC as follows:

[image]

Is it possible to send the whole traffic through the Internet and still be able to program it?  To make it a little bit more clear, something like:

[image]

Comment: "Ethernet IP"? Isn't that just... a regular LAN-like network?

Comment: “Programming via Ethernet IP" — what exactly does that mean? It would help if you could specify what device and IDE you are talking about. I assume the IDE connects to the device on a given IP address and TCP port to receive commands?

Comment: @grawity yes   it's a regular LAN.Like  network & at slhck  I'm use codesys IDE and a  device with codesys Runtime on it !

Comment: The obvious answer is IPv6, of course.

Comment: @MichaelHampton A simple programmable device is unlikely to support ipv6

Comment: @MichaelHampton Also, not every ISP supports IPv6.

Comment: So your PC is directly-connected to the internet? No router or other similar piece of networking equipment in between?

Comment: @grawity [Ethernet/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherNet/IP)  is an industrial automation protocol, not to be confused with IP over Ethernet :(

Comment: @richardb: I see. It still appears to run over TCP/IP and UDP/IP though.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## The simple (and unsafe) method

What you're looking for is called port forwarding <sup>[[1](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for)]</sup><sup>[[2](https://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/)]</sup>.

For example, let us assume the following:

- Your programmable device works on port `22` and has the IP `192.168.1.5`
- Your public IP is `122.176.11.55`

Then you can go into your router's setting and forward a WAN port (for eg, `8022`) to `192.168.1.5:22`.

Now, you can remotely access the device from anywhere through the internet by accessing `122.176.11.55:8022` instead of `192.168.1.5:22` in your IDE.

Keep in mind that unless you have a static IP, your public IP can change at any time, in which case you should check out [dynamic DNS services](https://www.howtogeek.com/66438/how-to-easily-access-your-home-network-from-anywhere-with-ddns/).

***NOTE***: unless your device has some method of authentication, someone with malicious intent will almost certainly find access to it on the open web. See below for safe alternative.

## The safe (and honestly not much more complicated) method

Leave a PC (or raspberry pi, or similar) connected to your network, and access *that* remotely instead through something safe like SSH, and then program your device through it over LAN.
This also has the added advantage of working even if your device doesn't use TCP or UDP :)

A bit tedious, yes. But safe.

Comment: It would also help to make a note, that if OP sets a portforwarding open to do this, everyone else in the whole world could potentially change the code. Unless there's some form of authentication too, sooner or later, portsniffers will find the port and a hacker will attempt to break in, that's a guarantee.

Comment: @LPChip Indeed! I should've mentioned that, my bad.

Comment: Nice addition. :) I would give you a +1 for it, but I already gave it earler, because even without the warning, it was already a good answer. :)

Comment: There's also the 'safe but more complicated method' of setting up a VPN.

Comment: @LPChip "Sooner" as in minutes or "Later" as in 10s of minutes?

Comment: @FreeMan later as in, it can take days before a bot crawler comes along, depending on what port you use, but sooner in the sense that, if you are unlucky, it can happen in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you disable password logins and make sure the device doesn't have a known password, for SSH to be safe? I know that some pre-configured OSes for those devices have very known password available on their websites.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Of course, you should do all the obvious basic security stuff. I just have no way of knowing what they are in this specific case.

Comment: @Engine Keep in mind, this will only work if you can specify a default gateway on said device. Otherwise packets will reach the device, but you will receive no response. But really, please go with the second option. It is much safer considering the services on the device were probably not designed to be "exposed" to the public internet.

Comment: I might mention that SSH is MADE for this kind of operation.  It allows you to use encryption keys instead of passwords (Disable password login completely, and consider moving the port!) and allows port forwarding.  Because of the encryption keys, an SSH connection can be made safely from a batch file without prompting for a password, and with port forwarding you can set it up so that (for instance) going to port 44444 on your "PC" will act exactly as if you'd gone to port 45678 on your remote device, once you create the script to start the connection, you don't have to think about it again.

Answer (score 14):

The one and only correct answer can be "VPN".

Simply using IPv6 would "work" (assuming the router isn't configured to firewall off the device, and all of ISP, device, and laptop support IPv6), but it is a terrible idea for the same reason port forwarding is.

Other than promoted by the well-known IPv6 propaganda, you actually do not *ever* want any of the devices on your LAN being uniquely identifiable or even accessible from the internet. No, that is *not* a good thing.

Port forwarding would "work" with good old IPv4, but it makes the device accessible not only to you but to everybody. Nobody knows, so that's no problem, right?
Well, there's an army of automated port scanners running 24/7 and scanning random addresses/ports in the hope anything, anywhere might possibly answer, so generally having *any* device that will answer to an external request online isn't optimal. If a device will happily have itself *programmed* according to what comes in via the network, that's a recipe for desaster.
The above is in principle true for VPN as well, but it's pretty much as good as you can get, if you want access. The only truly safe thing is no internet connection at all, which is not a practical option for obvious reasons. The next safest thing to "no internet" is VPN. Exactly one port on exactly one device (well, it depends, up to three ports), exposing VPN *and nothing else*, port-forwarded to the internet.

VPN lets you -- but nobody else -- access a device on your LAN via the internet *as if* you were on the same LAN (although a bit slower). It prevents unauthorized access, it provides confidentiality, and data integrity.

Virtually every no-shit router supports at least one flavor of VPN out of the box. Unluckily, depending on what router model you have, it may be a poor flavor of VPN or it may be poorly documented how to configure the remote computer. Still, despite the possible hassle of figuring out how to configure it -- if you have nothing better, that's by far the best option!
Most common NAS boxes support two or three no-suck methods of VPN, and every $20 credit-card sized 3 Watt computer can run a VPN server, no problem. Even many modern mobile phones support VPN without having to install extra software, so you can even access your home network when you're using your phone's mobile internet (via private hotspot, even).

For example, L2TP/IPSec may not be the most awesome choice, but it's 99% good and takes one minute to set up on my Disk Station and on my Samsung phone. Another minute if my Windows laptop is to use it as well (independently of the phone). No extra software needed.
OpenVPN takes like 3-5 minutes of setup because you'll have to download install the client software on the laptop. But in the greater picture, a 5 min setup counts as "zero", compared to being completely unsafe.

Comment: Buying 3rd-party services is not the only answer. You can get the same effect with SSH or RDP.

Comment: The two and only correct answers are VPN or SSH tunnels...Some VPN protocols aren't very good either at preventing MITM...

Comment: SSH is way cheaper, more convenient, and easier to set up and probably the better option in this scenario

Comment: @jpaugh: VPN does not involve any 3rd party services. While I'll readily agree that SSH can be made to work, it is nowhere near the same as VPN when it comes to ease of setup, no-extra-installs-no-hoops universal availability, and last but not least, seamless usability. Now, about RDP... you are of course joking, right? Not only is it the pristine implementation the probably most exploited software in the world (or at least in the top-5), but also the protocol itself is inherently insecure, using broken (workable, not theoretical) ciphers, and a TLS version which was superseded a decade ago.

Comment: -1 simply for "one and only" in the title, SSH with port forwarding is also completely valid and probably safer since you don't necessarily have to give remote access to your entire network, just one port of one device, and most likely it's easy to configure and you aren't relying on a router's random software implementation of a rarely used feature.

Answer (score 2):

Host a VPN, either in a router/security gateway appliance, or another box with port forwarding to that box. Whenever you want to work remotely, connect to the VPN, and you will see the embedded device as if it were on a local network. It would probably be a good idea to place the embedded device in an isolated subnet, to *help* prevent attacks on your main network if the VPN or the embedded device is compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Make Windows PC without IDE into a Linux PC in a reasonably secure configuration with sshd running. Port forward from your router to the SSH port on the Linux machine. Use SSH tunnels to connect to the embedded device IP. Then when programming on your remote machine with an IDE, you will connect to localhost instead of the LAN IP.

Listening on the internet with a hardened service like SSH is reasonably safe. Listening directly on the internet with development *anything* is a fabulously bad idea. SSH is a gatekeeper. If you make sure to verify the host key, it protects against MITM absolutely. It uses good cryptography. The tunneling setup does not involve routing or bridging but instead looks as if you are connecting directly from the SSHD machine. This is vastly simpler to setup correctly.

Comment: You can... Just run an SSH server on Windows, you don't _need_ Linux here.

Comment: "Then when programming on your remote machine with an IDE, you will connect to localhost instead of the LAN IP." This bit doesn't make sense to me, elaborate?

Comment: @rahuldottech SSH port forwarding works at the tcp level. On the server the sshd opens connections to the resource on the local lan and forwards the contents of that socket over SSH. On the remote machine the ssh client listens on a localhost port.  When you connect to localhost on that port it is the SSH client, and it just hooks the tcp connections together. Kinda weird but really versatile since there is no ip routing!

Answer (score -1):

I have recently come across a better solution for personal only remote access. First let's discuss the scope of the problem. There are three issues that come into play: the nat, the ip address, and the security. For example in the common cases where you wish to run a ssh or web server on a home network the traditional approach is port forwarding and dynamic dns and industry standard best practices for security. This has disadvantages for your case as your device does not have standard security. This can be mitigated by using ssh port forwarding as opposed to opening your device to the internet, but you still have to deal with nat traversal since your device (and the ssh server on your raspberry pi you are about to set up) does not have a publicly reachable IP address and the IP address of your router is subject to change (assuming there is only one nat between you and the internet) you still would need to setup port forwarding (or in the case of multiple routers, multiple port forwarding) and dynamic dns so you can still reach your ssh server.

There is however a simpler solution, and believe it or not that is tor hidden services. tor hidden services basically act as a port forward, but automatically handles nat traversal, and does not have a changing address so dynamic dns is not needed. There are of course issues of the onion address being hard to remember, but If you are the only user, you can write it down in one of your project files. I would recommend still paring this with a ssh server to provide authentication, but you may decide that the long onion address is enough. Also tor hidden services provide encryption of the entire link except for the last hop so the only way to get better is end to end encryption, but that would depend on the device you are programing.

Comment: Using onion services will only make this way more complicated with __no__ added benefits. Tor can be useful. Won't be in this case.